# CAST with different datatypes from UNION Select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm having an UNION Statement with different datatypes and want to sort them.

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT name, 'P' as 'type', to_char(order_number) as order_type FROM abc

   UNION ALL

   SELECT name, 'T' as 'type', to_char(name) as order_type FROM def
   )
ORDER BY
CASE type 
  WHEN 'P' THEN order_type
ELSE 
  order_type 
END
```

This works so far.

Now the content for the order_type from table `abc` is integer and from table `def` is varchar.
Thats why the order of the result is wrong. (e.g. 1000 is before 11)

I tried using

```
ORDER BY
CASE type WHEN 'P' THEN CAST(order_type AS NUMBER)
ELSE order_type END
```

in the order part but I'm getting

```
INCONSISTENT DATATYPES
```

What am I doing wrong?

table contents:

`abc`:

```
name          | order_number
'Example 1'   | 10001
'Example 2'   | 11
```

`def`:

```
name   | order_number
'Example 4' | 0
'Example 3'  | 0
```

Expected Result:

```
Example 2
Example 1
Example 3
Example 4
```

Comment: Is `'4'` here supposed to represent column 4. or the number 4? Neither really makes sense. If you made your fourth column alias a non-reserved word, say `as order_col`, then you could just `order by order_col`, surely? Am I missing something?

Comment: '4' stands for column 4. It does not change anything when switching to order by order_col... the CASE is the problem

Comment: You don't need the case though? That's what I'm confused by (as well as the code being invalid in various ways, which is always helpful); otherwise what is the `order` column for? You want to order by that fourth value, right, regardless of `type`?

Comment: first order_type contains number, order_type of the second table only varchars... withouth case it works, but the sorting is wrong

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want. I updated the answer...

Comment: First order-type isn't a number as you have `to_char` around it. `c` might be a number. So is `f` a string representation of a number? If so wouldn't you leave `c` alone and do `to_number(f)` instead? Showing some data and expected results would really help.

Comment: Updated the answer with expected result...

Comment: @frgtv10, I have posted a test case taking your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the constant `'4'` or `4` in the order by doesn't achieve anything; that won't be translated to the column position.

Whatever the original data types, the union will present the data from both branches as the same type (determined by the first branch). You've got `to_char(c)` which means `order_type` is a string; `f` is already a string but even if it was a number it would be implicitly converted to match.

```
CASE type WHEN 'P' THEN CAST(order_type AS NUMBER)
ELSE order_type END
```

When you do this order_type is a string; the `then` is turning it into a number, the `else` is not, so the data type is different.

If you want to order numerically then make `order_type` numeric and just order by that:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT a,b,'P' as "type", c as order_type FROM abc
   UNION ALL
   SELECT d,e,'T' as "type", to_number(f) as order_type FROM def
   )
ORDER BY order_type;
```

Or if you need the `order_type` in the result set to be a string, convert it back in the order-by clause:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT a,b,'P' as "type", to_char(c) as order_type FROM abc
   UNION ALL
   SELECT d,e,'T' as "type", f as order_type FROM def
   )
ORDER BY to_number(order_type);
```

... but that seems rather redundant.

Of course, this assumes all the values in `f` are actually valid numbers stored as strings (which is a whole different topic). If they cannot all be converted then you'll get an invalid-number error at some point either way; and then your best bet might be to pad the string result as @KimBergHansen suggests, though as he said non-integer values might give odd results, and you'd need to pick a suitably large length.

---

Based on your question edit, you seem to want the `abc` values first sorted by `order_num`, then the `def` values sorted by `name`. In that case use multiple elements:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT name, 'P' as order_type, order_num FROM abc
   UNION ALL
   SELECT name,'T' as order_type, null as order_num FROM def
   )
ORDER BY CASE WHEN order_type = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
  order_num,
  name;

NAME       ORDER_TYPE  ORDER_NUM
---------- ---------- ----------
Example 2  P                  11 
Example 1  P               10001 
Example 3  T                     
Example 4  T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a051/1) from your sample data.

Comment: @frgtv10 - updated based on your latest question edit, but still having to make assumptions about your logic...

Comment: @frgtv10 - if `order_num` is a string holding a number (which is bad practice) then you need `to_number(order_num)`, not `to_char()`...

Comment: Now I see where the problem is... I deleted the to_char() for the order_num in the select query. And then just use the order_by... omg its so easy.

Answer (score 1):

Your column ORDER_TYPE is a string and will sort as a string, so 11 comes before 2. You want to order those strings coming from table ABC as numbers and those strings coming from table DEF alphabetically.

One way could be:

```
ORDER BY CASE type WHEN 'P' THEN lpad(order_type,20,'0') ELSE order_type END
```

That order by is string ordering all the time, but by left-padding the numbers with zeroes, that will be ordered numerically (as you state it is integer data - if you had fractions that could complicate it a bit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The point over is that in your order by clause, you are mixing the data types

```
with t1(text) as (
  select '1' from dual union all
  select 'P' from dual union all
  select '4' from dual
  )
select * from t1
ORDER BY
CASE text 
  WHEN 'P' THEN CAST('4' AS NUMBER)
ELSE 
  '4'
END;
```

Error : `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR`

Here, char is mixed with number. To get a consistent data type returned from the case, you need to convert the else part into number making return from each condition of case as consistent as far as data type is concerned

```
with t1(text) as (
  select '1' from dual union all
  select 'P' from dual union all
  select '4' from dual
  )
select * from t1
ORDER BY
CASE text 
  WHEN 'P' THEN CAST('4' AS NUMBER)
ELSE 
  CAST('4' AS NUMBER) -- or just 4 without qoutes
END;
```

Output:

```
| TEXT |
|------|
|    1 |
|    4 |
|    P |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  select ename, to_char(sal) sal from emp)
  3  select ename ,sal  from data
  4  ORDER BY
  5  to_number(sal)
  6  /

ENAME      SAL
---------- ----------------------------------
SMITH      800
JAMES      950
ADAMS      1100
WARD       1250
MARTIN     1250
MILLER     1300
TURNER     1500
ALLEN      1600
CLARK      2450
BLAKE      2850
JONES      2975
SCOTT      3000
FORD       3000
KING       5000

14 rows selected.
```